# ko Uncaught ReferenceError foreach

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js, knockback.js

I know this sounds like a really simple issue, but this is driving me a little nutty.

I have an observable array of objects that I would like reflected in my html. So for each object in the html I would like to show a paragraph on the page. To do this I'm setting up the array in my viewModel

```
createViewModel: function(){
       var viewModel = kb.viewModel(this.model,{});
       viewModel.Objects = ko.observableArray(this.model.models);
       return viewModel;
},
```

and that array looks like this. [image: objects]

And then later on in the file I am applying my Binding for the page. I know this is working because I have other binding on the page not breaking. Just this one.

My html looks like this. I'm just trying to loop through the objects and show that p tag for each object.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Objects">
    <p>here</p>
</div>
```

I've tried just about everything I can think of. I've added ()'s after the Objects, I've read the docs from top to bottom and have read every thread that has had this issue. But nothing seems to work. Most of them say it's something wrong with the applyBindings, but that's the one thing I know is right.

Is there any way to fix this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: do you have a working sample of the issue? there's some code you're referencing that's not here; perhaps you could put together a jsfiddle?

Comment: @RoyJ, it's not throwing away the viewModel, it's returning it so I can use it in other places.

Comment: @dperry, What code am I referencing? To be honest I don't have time to create a js fiddle. I'm working on like eight different things here

Comment: @nemesv ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return Objects }"(…)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that I had copied from an older version. It truly is just return viewModel;

Comment: are you calling applyBindings with a target element? perhaps the foreach isn't in the bound part of the view

Comment: @dperry, I have an overall applyBinding's that attaches to the individual $el. It's working for everything else on the page and elsewhere in the app so that's the one thing I know is working. :)

Comment: Here's a fiddle that follows in a minimal way what you're doing. Right now, it works as expected. Maybe you can flesh it out with what you're doing in your code until it breaks.
http://jsfiddle.net/ouzjzfpw/

Comment: Second other commenters. We can't help you unless you help us reproduce your problem, not without resorting to *guessing* what's going on.

Comment: if you don't show the HTML and how you're applying the bindings, we cannot help you. That's not much to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to help you with out the whole sample. But I try to give some advice which helps me in the similar situation. First of all install plugins [Knockoutjs plugins](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en). The second try to change

> foreach: Objects

to

> foreach: $data.Objects

If error dissapear it mean you try to bind to other object not to your viewModel.